# Create dir with permissions using uid/gid?

Tags: permissions, docker

I know I can create a directory with permissions using

```
sudo install -d -m 0755 -o username -g groupname ./foo/bar
```

But how would I go about if I was in the midst of some remote machine/docker setup where the given user will connect from outside with a known id but has no local username? In other words, how can I use the install command with uid/gid instead of username/groupname? I want to avoid the multi step approach

```
mkdir -p ./foo/bar
sudo chown uid:gid ./foo/bar
sudo chmod ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [GNU `install`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/install-invocation.html), you can use either name or id with `-o` and `-g`:

> '`-g group`'
> '`--group=group`'
>
> Set the group ownership of installed files or directories to `group`.
> The default is the process's current group. `group` may be either a
> group name or a numeric group ID.
>
> '`-o owner`'
> '`--owner=owner`'
>
> If `install` has appropriate privileges (is run as root), set the
> ownership of installed files or directories to `owner`. The default is
> `root`. `owner` may be either a user name or a numeric user ID.

Comment: Thanks... kind of embarassing I overlooked that final sentence ;)